# PINCache performs as if being on a non ARC project

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm getting a Bad Access exception

*Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0))*

when deallocating the PinCache instance.
As I use ARC, the dispatch_release(_queue) should't be reached, but it does, and crashes. Any suggestions of why could this be happening?

This is the PINCache code.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    #if !OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC
    dispatch_release(_queue);
    dispatch_release(_lockSemaphore);
    _queue = nil;
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want here is:

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    ...
#endif
```

Or if you want to be *really* paranoid about it:

```
#if defined(__has_feature)
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
    ...
#endif
```

`OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC` is arguably an orthogonal construct/option.

Writing robust code that works identically in both ARC and non-ARC runtimes is tricky; Are you sure you need to do this at all?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem on PINCache project. 
The app crashed on the dealloc method in either PINMemoryCache or PINDiskCache.
Now it is fixed under the following issue.

https://github.com/pinterest/PINCache/issues/5